# How to use setTimeout to toggle a class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code uses a mouse click to toggle a class on an image. 
I'd like this transition to happen automatically using `setTimeout`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
    $("#cf2 img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
  });
});
```

Comment: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#cf2 img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.transparent {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cf2'>
  <img class='top' src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360
" alt="Image not found!" height="100" width="100">
</div>
<button id='cf_onclick'>Click Me</button>
```

Note:- You can set image by using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#cf2 img.top').toggleClass('transparent');
}, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, but you should pass as a second param the time in milliseconds... otherwise it's going to run immediately

Comment: @gabrielperales indeed you should, but it says that want to run it immediately, so 0ms is fine.

Comment: he said *automatically* not immediately :-). 0ms shouldn't has sense, should has?

Comment: @gabrielperales 0ms can also be considered automatically :p. It has some uses to set 0ms, but it can also be changed to your needs, so i think it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example `toggleClass` will be called automatically in every second.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#cf2 img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
}, 1000 ); // put timeout here, e.g. 1000 milliseconds is 1 second
```